# AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights - Filter Records by JSON filters on JSON log events

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a log group which accumulates JSON logs to each of its streams. These JSON logs look like this.

[image]

I want to filter logs where `"user" = "keet"`. AWS documentation explains on [Using Metric Filters to Extract Values from JSON Log Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html). I tried this using the AWS SDK, and it worked fine for the following code in NodeJS.

```
let params = {
    logGroupName: 'log-goupe-name', /* required */
    filterPattern: '{$.user=keet}',

};
cloudwatchlogs.filterLogEvents(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

**Question**:

Similarly, I want to know whether the same is possible on AWS Cloudwatch Insights Dashboard, on AWS Console? I know string pattern matching is possible. But I wanna know whether JSON field matching is possible on the Insights dashboard using `@filter`. The default query that comes is as follows.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

I tried following this answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725133/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-with-json-fields), and it still did not help. This is only for parsing data. My requirement is to filter logs based on value in JSON logs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can parse out the user from json like this:

```
parse @message '"user":"*"' as user
```

Depending on what you want to see on dashboard, you can filter out only particular users with this:

```
fields @message 
| parse @message '"user":"*"' as user
| filter user == "keet"
```

Result will be:

```
#    @message                            user
----------------------------------------------                            
1    info - {"user":"keet","age":30 }    keet
2    info - {"user":"keet","age":30 }    keet  
3    info - {"user":"keet","age":30 }    keet
4    info - {"user":"keet","age":30 }    keet
```

Also try just:

```
filter user == 'keet'
```

maybe Insights will auto-discover the fields. You can see the list of auto-discovered fields on the right, in **Discovered fields** section.

Comment: Amazing. This is what i was looking for. Any idea on how to parse compound JSON objects? `{"user":"keet","age":30,"name":{"first":"keet","last":"sugathadasa"}}`. I want to parse "last" as "last" column. I want to parse this as `name.first`  (compound manner).

Comment: You can do the same thing: `parse @message '"user":"*"' as user | parse @message '"first":"*"' as first | parse @message '"last":"*"' as last`, but this won't give you the `name.first` syntax. Can you try just `filter name.first == 'keet'` maybe Insights will autodiscover the fields. I'd suggest logging just the json bit (without `info -`).